# Error in twt[[1]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Tags: r

I am new to programming and getting an error as below.

> Error in twt[[1]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

My code:

```
myfun <- function(x){
mycorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(x))
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, content_transformer(function(x) iconv(enc2utf8(x), sub = "byte")))
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
removeURL <- function(x) gsub("https://['[:space:]]*","",x)
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, content_transformer(removeURL))
removeNL <- function(x) gsub("[^[:alpha:][:space:]]*","",x)
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, content_transformer(removeNL))
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, stripWhitespace)
mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, stemDocument)

stemCompletion2 <- function(x,dictionary) {
  x <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), ""))
  #Removing empty string 
  x <- x[x !=""]
  x <- stemCompletion(x, dictionary =dictionary)
  x <- paste(x, sep = "", collapse = "")
  PlainTextDocument(stripWhitespace(x))
  mycorpus <- tm_map(mycorpus, content_transformer(stemCompletion2), dictionary=mycorpus)
  return(mycorpus)
}
}

twt<- myfun(twetL)
strwrap(as.character(twt[[1]]))
```

- Error after executing the code

Comment: remove the stemCompletion2 function, you don't even use it

Comment: I don't know what `content_transformer` does but you end up using `stemCompletion2` in the definition of `stemCompletion2`.  Logically, it's hard to follow what your function is doing.  Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: reproducible example: `library(tm);
library(SnowballC); x="this is the corpus that I want to text mine"` What are you trying to do? What is the desired output?